# VS Code Keep Choosing PowerShell for Running Python Script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Anaconda as Python Distribution and VS Code recognized it well. I can change Python interpreter easily. I also set the terminal default profile as `Command Prompt`. When I open terminal using shortcut `` Ctrl+` ``, the terminal opened successfully using `Command Prompt` and even activates the conda environment. The problem occurred when I click `Run Python File in Terminal`. Instead of using `Command Prompt`, the terminal that opened is `PowerShell`. And because `conda` is not in `PATH`, it raises exception like this

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Why is this happening? Terminal default profile already set as `Command Prompt` but running python file keep opening `PowerShell`.

Comment: this is known bug that will be solved in the next version 1.60.1

Comment: @adam may I see github issue or article about that bug? I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Link provided by @VonC:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c765e70cf92bc4d2f08bdaa11ed1231063b7aa39